# Stop button click event on other button click

Tags: c#

how to access two button click method if first button doing work when we click second button?
I tried to access other button click event when first button click event is performing operation and I want to stop this execution and perform another operation

Comment: Could you show the codes of your both events

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to do some reading about asynchronous programming and then implement [Cooperative Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When you press the second button:

1. check that a task is in progress
2. if an operation is in progress, cancel the ongoing task *and wait for it to 'complete'* (cancel successfully)
3. run your new operation

Comment: I have two button in which one is inserting data into table by calling function in other class and I need to stop this insertion when click on stop button

Comment: @user3534716 if you want a code sample, post some code!